# Color Converter DSP ProcessOutput always returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, ms-media-foundation

I need to convert video frames from RGB32 to IYUV but the Color Converter MFT refuses to process samples. For every frame I call IMFTransform::ProcessInput() and IMFTransform::ProcessOutput() but I receive **MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT**. If I try to feed MFT with another sample i get the **MF_E_NOTACCEPTING** error.

Below I paste a code to show my problem. Hopefully you guys will be able to help.

First I create Media types:

```
//DSP input MediaType
CHECK_HR(hr = MFCreateMediaType(&m_pInputMediaType));   
CHECK_HR(hr =  m_pInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));   
CHECK_HR(hr =  m_pInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32))
CHECK_HR(hr =  m_pInputMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive))
CHECK_HR(hr =  MFSetAttributeSize(m_pInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_pStreamParams->StreamWidth, m_pStreamParams->StreamHeight))
CHECK_HR(hr =  MFSetAttributeRatio(m_pInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, m_pStreamParams->StreamFramerate, 1))
CHECK_HR(hr =  MFSetAttributeRatio(m_pInputMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));  

    //DSP output MediaType
CHECK_HR(hr = MFCreateMediaType(&m_pIntermediateMediaType));   
CHECK_HR(hr =  m_pIntermediateMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));   
CHECK_HR(hr =  m_pIntermediateMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_IYUV));
CHECK_HR(hr =  m_pIntermediateMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
CHECK_HR(hr =  MFSetAttributeSize(m_pIntermediateMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_pStreamParams->StreamWidth, m_pStreamParams->StreamHeight));
CHECK_HR(hr =  MFSetAttributeRatio(m_pIntermediateMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, m_pStreamParams->StreamFramerate, 1));
CHECK_HR(hr =  MFSetAttributeRatio(m_pIntermediateMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));
```

Then I initialize the DSP and set MediaTypes

```
CHECK_HR(hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CColorConvertDMO, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pColorDSP)));
CHECK_HR(hr = m_pColorDSP->SetInputType(0, m_pInputMediaType, 0));
CHECK_HR(hr = m_pColorDSP->SetOutputType(0, m_pIntermediateMediaType, 0));
```

And my frame processing method

```
HRESULT LibStreaming3::WriteFrame(DWORD* videoFrameBuffer)

{
IMFSample *pRGBSample = NULL;
IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;


if(!m_bStreaming)
{
    LOG("Failed: Not streaming!");
    return E_FAIL;
}
assert(m_pStreamParams);
assert(m_pH264Encoder);
assert(m_pColorDSP);
const LONG cbWidth = 4 * m_pStreamParams->StreamWidth;
const DWORD cbBuffer = cbWidth * m_pStreamParams->StreamHeight;

BYTE *pData = NULL;

// Create a new memory buffer.
HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

// Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = MFCopyImage(
        pData,                      // Destination buffer.
        cbWidth,                    // Destination stride.
        (BYTE*)videoFrameBuffer,    // First row in source image.
        cbWidth,                    // Source stride.
        cbWidth,                    // Image width in bytes.
        m_pStreamParams->StreamHeight                // Image height in pixels.
        );
}
if (pBuffer)
{
    pBuffer->Unlock();
}
do 
{

// Set the data length of the buffer.
CHECK_HR(hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer));

// Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
CHECK_HR(hr = MFCreateSample(&pRGBSample));
CHECK_HR(hr = pRGBSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer));

// Set the time stamp and the duration.
CHECK_HR(hr = pRGBSample->SetSampleTime(m_rtStart));
CHECK_HR(hr = pRGBSample->SetSampleDuration(m_rtDuration));
/************************************************************************/
/* CONVERT COLORS                                                       */
/************************************************************************/

MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER IYUVOutputDataBuffer;
IYUVOutputDataBuffer.dwStreamID = 0;
IYUVOutputDataBuffer.dwStatus = 0;
IYUVOutputDataBuffer.pEvents = NULL;
IYUVOutputDataBuffer.pSample = NULL;

DWORD dwDSPStatus = 0;
//IMFSample* pIYUVSample = NULL;
MFT_INPUT_STREAM_INFO info;
hr = m_pColorDSP->GetInputStreamInfo(0,&info );
hr = m_pColorDSP->ProcessInput(0, pRGBSample, 0); //Will provide only one sample, every next call will result in MF_E_NOTACCEPTING
hr = m_pColorDSP->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &IYUVOutputDataBuffer,&dwDSPStatus); // Always returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT


} while (false);
m_rtStart += m_rtDuration;
SafeRelease(&pRGBSample);
SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
return hr;
}
```

Best regards,
Pawel

Comment: If you can choose between MFT and DMO modes of this DSP, DMO might be simpler to use. All the use is the same, just simpler and is known to work fine.

Comment: After spending some time on this I realized that I need to create output sample and buffer on my own. Previously I mistakenly assumed that Color Converter MFT will automatically allocate all needed resources. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and it was due to giving `ProcessInput` and invalid sample. Instead of reporting an error it happily ignored it and so resulted in a `MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT` from `ProcessOutput`