# How to render YUV422 data and RGB raw data by Direct2D?

Tags: direct2d

I want to render YUV422 data and RGB8 data from following GiGE Vision Camera by using Direct2D.

[HB-20000-SB (Emergent  Vision Technologies)](https://emergentvisiontec.com/products/area-scan-cameras/25-gige-area-scan-cameras-hb-series/hb-20000-sb/)

I learned direct2D in Microsoft site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal

And I understood how to render image files by using Direct2D

1. Image files (jpeg, bmp, tiff, ...) can be passed to Direct2D by using CreateDecoderFromFilename().
2. Rendering the image by using DrawImage()

[Direct2D custom image effects sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/D2DCustomEffects)

However, I don't know how to pass YUV422 data and RGB raw to Direct2D.
Could Anyone advice to me?

Regards,
hiro

Comment: Direct2D only understands RGB32. You could use Media Foundation Color Converter DSP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/colorconverter something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588349/color-converter-dsp-processoutput-always-returns-mf-e-transform-need-more-input or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341038/imftransform-interface-of-color-converter-dsp-giving-e-invalidarg-on-setinputtyp

Comment: @Simon Mourier
Thank you for your comment.

I will check Media Foundation API.